# How to create a delete button in ImageField in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to programming and I'm taking my first steps, especially in django, in this case I used ImageField to upload images on the site I'm programming, but it only shows the path of the image and I was wondering how I could add a delete button to the page to edit a post...

[image]

Comment: Can you share your model? Add `null=True` and `blank=True` to the image field if you want to allow the field to not have a value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need to delete an image, as you change the image the old image would be replaced by the new one. and in default django admin you have the clear option, only if you have set image filed as `models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)`.

I suggest you using [django-cleanup](https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/), it automatically deletes files for `FileField`, `ImageField` and subclasses. When a `FileField`’s value is changed and the model is saved, the old file is deleted. When a model that has a `FileField` is deleted, the file is also deleted. A file that is set as the `FileField`’s default value will not be deleted.